# How do I circumvent Facebook's blocking of Pidgin?

Tags: facebook, login

I could connect to Facebook via Pidgin just fine until one night, when Facebook sent me a message about suspicious account access.

[image]

I stupidly clicked "I don't recognize".

Ever since, I get some "not authorized" error-message when trying to log in to Facebook chat via Pidgin.

I checked if anything else might have caused the problem, but found nothing. So I assume Facebook blocked Pidgin indeed. Is there a way to circumvent this blockage?

Comment: Have you looked under Facebook's Security settings?

Comment: The problem is not that Facebook is blocking Pidgin as such, but it's blocking your attempts to login via Pidgin because you told it not to authorise the login.

Comment: Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=devices&view and see if there's any information about blocked connections.

Comment: I looked at the security settings, there's nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an app password, in the "app password" section on https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=devices&view